# Spring WebFlux + ReactiveMongoDB, Can't save entity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux

I expect that after the execution of the program, Rubber will be saved in the mongo. The result is 200 O.K, but nothing was saved to the database, I suspect that the problem is in the doOnSuccess method. How to use it? Or what else could be the problem?

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<Rubber> create(@RequestBody Rubber rubber) {
    return rubberService.create(rubber);
}



@Override
public Mono<Rubber> create(Rubber rubber) {
    return Mono.just(rubber)
            .map(rubberToRubberEntityConverter::convert)
            .doOnSuccess(rubberRepository::save)
            .doOnError((throwable) -> Mono.error(new ApplicationException("Can't create ruber :( ", throwable)))
            .map(rubberEntityToRubberConverter::convert);
}



@Repository
public interface RubberRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<RubberEntity, String> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reactive chain isn't set up correctly:

```
return Mono.just(rubber)
        .map(rubberToRubberEntityConverter::convert)
        .doOnSuccess(rubberRepository::save)
```

You're not actually doing anything reactive here - you're taking a value, wrapping it in a `Mono`, converting it (synchronously), then performing a side-effect (also synchronously.) In this case, your side-effect is simply setting up the reactive chain to save to the repository (which will return a `Mono`), but **since that `Mono` is never subscribed to, the save never actually occurs.**

Your `doOnError()` call has a similar issue - you're again returning a `Mono` rather than performing a side-effect. Instead, you almost certainly want to use `onErrorMap()` to convert between one error and another.

In short, any time you use `doOnSuccess()`, `doOnError()` etc. and use a method that returns a publisher of some description, it's almost always going to be the wrong thing to do. Using `Mono.just()` is also a hint that you're not starting with a reactive chain - not necessarily *wrong* in and of itself, but it can be a warning sign that you're not actually creating a "real" reactive chain.

Instead, you probably want something like:

```
return rubberRepository.save(rubberToRubberEntityConverter.convert(rubber))
        .onErrorMap((throwable) -> new ApplicationException("Can't create rubber :( ", throwable))
        .map(rubberEntityToRubberConverter::convert);
```

Comment: @ocathern it makes no sense for your converter to be reactive unless it's blocking somehow (which it's almost certainly not.) So that's fine as it is.